# How many amps is needed from a 12V system to power a 7.4V 5A system

Tags: voltage, dc, amperage

I have a circuit that runs at 7.4V and 5 amps. A 12V system can also power it. I was wondering how to determine what the amp draw would be on the 12V system to produce 5A at 7.4V. This is all in DC.

I tried to find a site that would figure it out but no luck.

Comment: "A 12v system can also power it" - so it says it accepts 12 V, and you intend to run it on 12 V? If so, we'd need to see its datasheet or you would have to measure the actual current. Or do you mean to say that you intend to convert 12 V to 7.4 V and then feed 7.4 V to the load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How many amps is needed from a 12v system to power a 7.4v 5a system*

You need to supply up to 37 watts (7.4 volts × 5 amps). If your regulator was 100% efficient you would need to supply 37 watts from the 12 volts; that's 3.083 amps. That would be best served using a [synchronous buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#Specific_structures) that can have an efficiency of maybe 96%.

So, the current supplied from the 12 volts would be a little higher at 3.2 or 3.3 amps.

Comment: So basically the equation is 7.4 * 5 / 12 = 3..083? This is basically what I am looking for.  Thank you.